# GUI Control For Audio Presentation

Tags: .net, c++, user-interface, audio, rtp

I need GUI control for audio file presentation.  The language is not very important but it should run on windows platform.

I should be able to :-

- load the file
- play the sound
- put and move markers across the audio bar.
- it would be nice if it can load itself from RTP wireshark captures (and not wav files).

An example may be seen in audacity (may be someone even had an experience extracting it from there).  Writing nyquist scripts in audacity is not a good option because I have to operate on RTP captures and not on raw sound samples.

[image: audacity]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/images/audacity-macosx.png))</sub>

Another example of such control is wireshark RTP analyzer.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try AudioExCs example from Alvas.Audio library http://alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx